# Modifying ticksize when resizing the chart

Tags: d3.js

I am using the trick of sizing the ticks on my axes in order to render a grid effect on my chart.  The problem I have is that I am not able to work out how to resize the ticks on my y axis when the width of the chart changes due to a window resize.

The code that I have to initialize my chart is as follows:

```
  this._xRange = d3.time.scale().range([0, chartWidth]);
  this._yRange = d3.scale.linear().range([chartHeight, 0]);
  this._xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(this._xRange)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickSize(-chartHeight)
    .tickSubdivide(true);
  this._yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(this._yRange)
    .orient("left")
    .tickSize(-chartWidth)
    .tickSubdivide(true);
```

When the chart is resized, I am recalculating the width and height of the chart and attempting to redraw the axes.  For the y axis I am using the following code:

```
  // Redraw the y axis
  this._yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(this._yRange)
    .orient("left")
    .tickSize(-chartWidth)
    .tickSubdivide(true);
  this._chart.call(this._yAxis.orient("left"));
```

This is failing with the following exception in the browser console:

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before
which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node. "Error:
Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new
node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I have hit upon a solution.  It appears that I need to remove the existing y axis, create a new generator and then add the new generator to the chart.  I am using the following code to do this:

```
  d3.select(".y.ResourceStatsAxis").remove();
  this._yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(this._yRange)
    .orient("left")
    .tickSize(-chartWidth)
    .tickSubdivide(true);
  this._chart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y ResourceStatsAxis")
    .call(this._yAxis);
```